# The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Field'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

I'm working on a flow that needs to create a column in a SharePoint library. I'm using the SP REST API for this. When I send start the I send the API request I get the following error:"

The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Field'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using configuration settings like below:

[image]

**Uri**:

```
_api/lists/getbytitle('FlowLibrary')/fields
```

Where `FlowLibrary` display name of document library

**Headers**:

```
accept: application/json;odata=verbose
content-type: application/json;odata=verbose
```

**Body**:

```
{
  '__metadata': {'type':'SP.FieldText'},
  'FieldTypeKind': 2,
  'Title': 'field title',
  'StaticName': 'field name'
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much